# Convert a date into a date with day of the week php native

Tags: php, date, zend-framework

Basically I want to convert this date : 2016/12/18
 to : Sunday, December 18, 2016.

I'm using zend framework and php 5.4

I'm really new with this I tried to use:

```
date( "Y/m/d", strtotime( $model->startDate))->toString(Zend_Date::DATE_FULL)   ;
```

but brings: 
 Call to a member function toString() on a non-object
Any idea? It's possible to make this on php native?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 

  $x = "2016/12/18";

  echo date( "l, F d, Y", strtotime($x)); 

?>
```

**Will return:**

```
Sunday, December 18, 2016
```

**---**

**Check here for date parameters:**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: wuoaa let me test

Comment: yeap.. that works... Im going to read more about date native function... thanks

Comment: @arnoldssss Accept the answer so this question will be marked as SOLVED. Thanks and good luck further.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one

```
echo date('l F d,m',strtotime('2016/12/18'))
```